# Function to pull data from user meta not working

Tags: functions, user-meta

So I am attempting to create a series of functions that calculate a price based on a client level I have set for each customer. Some customers may have a special deal.

To do this, I created a custom meta field in the user meta that allows me to assign either High, medium, or low to that client.

I then created a function meant to determine what the client level is and use that for the price calculations.

If a client is not logged in, or a field is empty, the default is set to High

I tried two versions of this function and put it in a plugin to test with a simple echo statement, but neither seem to be changing the result to anything besides high, despite the meta field being set to low.

if you can help me figure out what I am missing, that would be great. 
First Attempt:

```
function get_client_lvl () {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    If ($user_id == 0) {
        return 'high';
    } Else {
        $client_lvl= get_user_meta($user_id, wpcf-client-lvl, true); 
        if (empty($client_lvl)) {
            return 'high';
        } Else {
            return $client_lvl;
        }
    }
}

$client_lvl=get_client_lvl();

echo $client_lvl;
```

Second Attempt

```
function get_client_lvl () {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $client_lvl= get_user_meta($user_id, wpcf-client-lvl, true);

    If ($user_id == 0 || empty($client_lvl)) {
        return 'high';
    } Else {
        return $client_lvl;
    }
}

$client_lvl=get_client_lvl();

echo $client_lvl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass the `$key` argument on `get_user_meta()` function, you don't pass a valid argument. The `$key` must be a string according to the [documentation page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). It represents the value of `meta_key` in the `wp_usermeta` table.

If with wpcf-client-lvl is actually a variable that contains the name of the field ( lets say `$wpcf-client-lvl = 'client_level'` ) replace `'wpcf-client-lvl'` with `$wpcf-client-lvl`. My guess was that this was the actual `meta_key` name.

I also change some of the syntax code if you don't mind :)

So I believe you copy / paste the following code it will work :

```
function get_client_lvl(){

    $global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    if ($user_id == 0)
        return 'high';

    else {

        $client_lvl= get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpcf-client-lvl', true); 

        if (empty($client_lvl))
            return 'high';

        else
            return $client_lvl;

    }

}

$client_lvl = get_client_lvl();

echo $client_lvl;
```

**UPDATE**

In order for the `get_current_user_id()` to return the ID you must either include **pluggable.php** ( which I don't think is a good approach ) or use global variables to get id. I changed the code using the `global $current_user`.

Comment: Yes wpcf-client-lvl is supposed to be the field name created by the wp-types plugin. I tried adding your code with no success.

Comment: Ok, I added an echo code in the function to determine what user_id it is generating, and for some reason it is generating an ID of 0 even though I am listed in the database as user ID 1 as I should be. Any ideas?

Comment: took some work but I figured it out. it needed a require  pluggable.php for it to know what the function was.

Comment: I updated the answer using a different approach which I find to be more efficient. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Ok, well I tried your method, but if current user is not defined or pluggable is not initiated, then it breaks the site. The only other think I can think of to get rid of the pluggable requirement is to tell the function to load after all other files are initiated in wordpress. But I'm not sure how to do that. Although, since the actual call of the function will not be in the function itself, maybe it will work just fine.  The actual use of this function is called within another function that is called on page templates. What do you think?

Comment: Here is my code start. 

require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
function get_client_lvl(){

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
       
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

Comment: I am a little bit confused. This function is supposed to be inside a plugin or inside functions.php of a theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this: [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) and section about capatibilities.

You need to use the user global. Your function don't know the user id. You can declare argument (`$user_id`) or use `global $wp_user`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well the very first line of the function determines userid if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes it determine user id in the loop, but your function need global to really be a part of your loop. See arguments of a function. You can change the call and the function like this : get_clt_lvl($user_id)...